# show Marker infowindow when a Marker changed in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

JS:

```
 var map;

 function pageLoad() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 3,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.454543, 35.812997),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 }

 function getRandomArbitary(min, max) {
     return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }

 function SetLocation() {
     var latitude = getRandomArbitary(1, 30);
     var longitude = getRandomArbitary(1, 30);
     var locationlatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         'position': locationlatLng,
         'map': map
     });
     map.panTo(locationlatLng);
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 600px">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SetLocation();">Set Custom Location</a>
```

when the user click on set custom location a new marker is created and the map is pined to it but how can i display the infowindow dynamically when the new marker is created ?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the marker (with google.maps.event.trigger) after you create it (of course you will need a click listener to open the infowindow, and some content for the infowindow):

```
var map;
var infowindow;

 function pageLoad() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 3,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.454543, 35.812997),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });
     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 }

 function getRandomArbitary(min, max) {
     return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }

 function SetLocation() {
     var latitude = getRandomArbitary(1, 30);
     var longitude = getRandomArbitary(1, 30);
     var locationlatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         'position': locationlatLng,
         'map': map
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e){
        if (e && e.latLng) { 
          infowindow.setContent("location:" +e.latLng);
        } else {
          infowindow.setContent("location:" +marker.getPosition());
        }  
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
     });
     google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');

     map.panTo(locationlatLng);
 }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', pageLoad);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_openInfoWindowOnChange.html)